# Migrate con postgresql django 2.2

Tags: django

Este es mi archivo settings, configuracion de base de datos:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'prestaciones_sociales.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'prestaciones_sociales',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1xxx',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

> No, entiendo porque, sigue generando mis tablas en sqlite3. ya elimine varias veces la migracion y reiniciado el migrate, pero no ha funcionado que estoy haciendo, mal. Agradezco sugerencias.

Comment: Borraste el código que genera la migración a sqlite3 ?

Comment: Si, ya lo habia borrado, pero mi solucion fue crear un proyecto nuevo, con un nombre nuevo, y se soluciono el problema, no se porque, pero fue mi solucion, al estar trabajando tambien con entorno virtual. no se si eso me estaba generando conflictos.